# make and unnecessary callback creations and assignations (initialState...)?

Tags: ocaml, reason, reason-react

I don't understand the way `make` work:

```
let component = ReasonReact.reducerComponent("Greeting");

let make = (~name, _children) => {
  ...component,
  initialState: () => 0, /* here, state is an `int` */
  render: (self) => {
    let greeting =
      "Hello " ++ name ++ ". You've clicked the button " ++ string_of_int(self.state) ++ " time(s)!";
    <div>{ReasonReact.stringToElement(greeting)}</div>
  }
};
```

As far as I understand, `make` will be called every time the `<Greeting>` component is used in a parent component render method, so it will be called multiple times.

But this also means the component record will create multiple times the `initialState` function right?

I don't understand how it makes sense to assign the `initialState` some function every time we create the React element, while it will only be called when the element gets mounted and will have no effect on updates.

I take `initialState` as an example, but could also say the same for other lifecycle callbacks too.

Comment: If your initial state doesn't depend on your initial props, you can lift it out:
`let initialState = () => 0;
let make = (~name, _children) => {
  ...component,
  initialState,
  render: ...
};`

Comment: sure I can do that but when it depends on initial props I still don't see the value of recreating that function everytime :) not really looking for perf workarounds but more to understand the design decision behind this

Comment: Ah, sorry. So, since `make` is called on every render, `initialState` needs to be lazily-evaluated (what you'd model as a call-by-name in Scala). This is because it should be evaluated only on the first `make` call, not after that. They simply made a choice to use a function for this. It's also possible to model as an OCaml `lazy` value ( https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Lazy.html ), but it comes to more or less the same thing in the compiled output.

Comment: Ok, by-name Scala parameters talk to me. So basically you say that the initialState function is there, but will actually be created only when it will be called? So multiple lazy variables might be created but a single one will lead to a function creation?

Comment: Correct, I don't see a way around that with the current design...

Answer (score 6):

> As far as I understand, `make` will be called every time the `<Greeting>` component is used in a parent component render method, so it will be called multiple times.

Yes, `make` is called for every render.

[In this example](https://astrada.github.io/reason-react-playground/?reason=LYewJgrgNgpgBASQHYGcCWZ4F44G8BQccsALnAMYjAAOISMSZOASjAIYp2tvkkB0KEmxIxYKFAGEqteowAUAIgBCUNgoCUAbnz5ScYGwDW2OHIB+SNsBgAaOAH1yACzRQwAJwbq4WAHx5COAApFD4oEABzRQNjRFQMGA1tIgIiPnTKGjoGEjsAegAqOBRqTzYwOBIneBEaVREAchQ4ECqYdzhMADM2aBJmtEYQOGrPIgK8wM8kTHcALgcUUS6ffwAeMDQAN39cbk4kbl4BEndBiIAVEABRWGt5S2t1AF84NbzNnfxn5Lgf7+0OlAkFgcAA4p4YCRzj4AiQAJ7UeA8aF0HyBAA+cAkUDQ5EMgIRSOKQhEsNSFBAEEYC0GJABOj0mRkOVh+y47GOnkg5HaUiyshIigAsvCAGIgdzAJKMqH6IwmOSOFxuabePwBNIZaTZRg2QKDNDQthQADKpJgCzk6t2ITCkUUyCNaBNJOEiS0eEo1JICwADM9nvqiNyILz5qYUWg6HZBO6bYEiCgAO5G5yR3jRpDeClELE4vGGVZwdmHTn8ACq1DA7rkuG9NLdIj4DbIAGo4ABGZ7qRN-YNwaazK1LKBdG2aojBULhKIKIftGVT4hy6ziNgREwKAv4mAVBRwNsdwRnJARewgLr2OlyUddE7ultUxjeI9wA-Qte39QKX5EDbbL4fb-gARhAJAkGidA7oYWC4PYMBbKyGp3gIDBgHIMEvP4cilkc-AnucVy3DA9xCgoAASojhAAhBo3jvGBEF0EBy7-sg6CYHAjwwFga4oBu8B5KxU7vJ8InPAy-z4PhAAiADywqsHwC7uMRdw5AA6kaTgIBhawQjAUIwsJdgKKUiFoDAyZJEAA), `make Inside` is printed in the console every time the button is pressed –which causes a new render of the `Inside` component.

I was curious to understand better why this was happening, so sharing it here in case someone else finds it interesting. The way the implementation works today is approximately as follows:

- `<Greeting name="John" />` is transformed into `ReasonReact.element(Greeting.make(~name="John", [||]))` by the Reason ppx. You can find the implementation [in the main Reason repo](https://github.com/facebook/reason/tree/b8240a193941cb23adf53849d11c4262b046e6d5/src/ppx).
- In that statement, `Greeting.make` is the `make` function you are making reference to, the same function that each ReasonReact component has to define.
- `ReasonReact.element` is where the magic happens. This function will call `createElement` the following way ([source code](https://github.com/reasonml/reason-react/blob/eafe22ae03060ed339e144149d886e62b6a4e167/src/ReasonReact.re#L888-L892)):

```js
createElement(
  component.reactClassInternal,
  ~props={"key": key, "ref": ref, "reasonProps": element},
  [||]
)
```

- The `element` passed as the prop `reasonProps` is actually the full component "template" that is returned by `make` (see the assignment [a few lines above](https://github.com/reasonml/reason-react/blob/eafe22ae03060ed339e144149d886e62b6a4e167/src/ReasonReact.re#L880)).
- `component.reactClassInternal` points to a React component that I will be calling `WiringComponent` for simplicity. What this `WiringComponent` does in essence is to declare all React lifecycle methods and implement them by just delegating the actual behavior to the functions that come from the "template" declared with `make`. These functions are picked from the `reasonProps` prop that is passed to this `WiringComponent`. You can see the implementation of this component [here](https://github.com/reasonml/reason-react/blob/eafe22ae03060ed339e144149d886e62b6a4e167/src/ReasonReact.re#L250-L798).

So, even if `make` is called once for every render as you mention, in reality what is being rendered is something like `<WiringComponent reasonProps=Greeting.make(...) />`. Then, when `WiringComponent.getInitialState` is called (just once per component instance, as usual), [it will delegate that call to `Greeting.initialState`](https://github.com/reasonml/reason-react/blob/eafe22ae03060ed339e144149d886e62b6a4e167/src/ReasonReact.re#L330).

> But this also means the component record will create multiple times the `initialState` function right?

That's what the code seems to be doing. Solving this doesn't seem trivial to me. Given that labelled arguments are being used to model the components props, there is no way to memoize `make` without giving up the type safety, as there can be many "flavors" of this function (one for each component).

Comment: thanks for the explainations. Not sure what you mean by the "flavors". What I'd like to understand is the design decisions behind this make function. Couldn't we declare the functions like `initialState` in another place so that it would only be created once per component instance?

Comment: Again, not a contributor so take this with a grain of salt (i'm also curious to know what the creators of ReasonReact would have to say).

What I meant with "flavors" is that each component has different prop types. If we combine that with the decision of implementing props as labelled arguments, then it becomes really hard (impossible?) to have a "ReactComponent" record that holds all that information. How would the type of the `render` function look like?

Comment: Unfortunately I might not know enough Ocaml yet to understand what you mean :) will try to see if someone can help me understand in Discord

Comment: @SebastienLorber you can define the function elsewhere and reference it inside the component.

Comment: that's what Yawar said but it won't work if the initialState need to read props